# onclick event not working, instead it triggering while page load

Tags: javascript

In the following code I simply want the number of matched element by tag name, But it returns 0 and it alerts while page load (not on click as I want). Cannot find any mistake over an hour

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>

<script language="javascript">

    document.getElementById("all").onclick = alert( document.getElementsByTagName("a").length);

</script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="all" class="a">Click</div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div> 

</body>
</HTML>
```

I'm a total newbie in JavaScript

Comment: `onclick` expects a reference to a **function** to execute when the event happens. You're **immediately calling** `alert()`, which returns `undefined`. You could use something like: `.onclick = function () { alert("blah blah"); };`

Comment: Did as you said But It's not responding anything on clicking over the "all" identified element

Comment: You're also setting the `onclick` property **before** the element is rendered and could be found with `document.getElementById()`. So `document.getElementById("all")` returns `null` and is actually throwing an exception (that you could see in your browser's console). Move your code to right before the `</body>`

Comment: Sorry for disturbing @lan, But I have another question. Which things should I keep in <head> tag then?

Comment: You're not disturbing me :) You can still keep your JavaScript in the `<head>` tag, and you can have it set to run when the DOM is ready. For example, the other answer uses `window.onload`, which would be great. It says "run this code when the DOM is ready"...and in your case, "this code" refers to the `.onclick` binding. The other things I put in the `<head>` are CSS, like `<style>` or `<link />` tags, as well as `<meta />` tags

Answer (score 3):

A couple of problems.  The first one is pointed by @Ian in his comment on your question and the second one is you are calling `getElementsByTagName("a")` when in your code you do not have any `<a>` tags.  You need to call `getElementsByClassName("a")` instead.

```
document.getElementById("all").onclick = function() {
    alert( document.getElementsByClassName("a").length);
}
```

**Update:**

After Ian's comment, double checked jsfiddle and found that it had `onLoad` selected.  So here is the corrected code with `window.onload` and updated jsfiddle:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("all").onclick = function() {
    alert( document.getElementsByClassName("a").length);
  };
};
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZavDr/) of this.

Comment: Oh Ya! I changed it, But still not responding anything :-( I'm using touchscreen phone. Is there anything to do with it?

Comment: Ahh good catch, I didn't even bother looking at the HTML haha. Unfortunately, our suggestions *still* aren't enough! This code is executed before the element is rendered, and won't be found!

Comment: @Ario, it's working fine.  Please check the jsfiddle link under Update above.

Answer (score 2):

You are running the JS before even DOM is loaded. That means element `all` does not exist in the DOM when JS is running. Write like below, and that is the way to do.

```
var attachEve = function(){
   document.getElementById("all").onclick = function() {
       alert( document.getElementsByClassName("a").length);
   }
}
window.onload = attachEve;
```

It should work!. Without `window.onload` works in jsfiddle because jsfiddle runs the JS in `window.onload` context.